# Is there any calender widget available in tcl tk that can be used by an user in a tcltk UI to select date

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I am trying to make an UI using tcltk and I wanted to give a calender option to users against a date type entry field so that they choose the date from the calender.

Is there any calender widget available in tcl tk? Or do I need to write code to create a calender? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Tklib](http://core.tcl.tk/tklib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/toc.html) has [calendar](http://core.tcl.tk/tklib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tklib/files/modules/widget/widget_calendar.html) and a [date entry](http://core.tcl.tk/tklib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tklib/files/modules/widget/widget_dateentry.html) widgets.

You may also search for ideias at the [tclers' wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/_/search?S=calendar&_charset_=UTF-8).